# Adding a redirection to a bash command array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, io-redirection

I am storing a command to execute in a bash array, example:

```
declare -a cmd=("sudo" "dnf" "update")
"${cmd[@]}"

Last metadata expiration check: 0:24:45 ago on Fri 07 Jan 2022 03:35:34 PM EST.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

Now, say I want to redirect the output to make it less noisy. This works:

```
"${cmd[@]}" &>/dev/null
```

But I would prefer to store the redirect with the command array so it can be added/removed like any other command in the array:

```
declare -a cmd=("sudo" "dnf" "update" "&>/dev/null")
"${cmd[@]}"

Last metadata expiration check: 0:29:14 ago on Fri 07 Jan 2022 03:35:34 PM EST.
No match for argument: &>/dev/null
```

The output isn't being redirected, the final array element is just being passed like a normal argument. Is there any way to get this work (i.e. judicious use of eval) or a better strategy?

XY statement:
I am trying to use conditionals to make my program output silent. I can do this with:

```
silent=true
cmd=("sudo" "dnf" "update")
if silent; then
  "${cmd[@]}" &>/dev/null
else # Be noisy
  "${cmd[@]}"
fi
```

This results in lots of duplicated code over the course of my program (every debug operation needs multiple command execution lines). Instead I would prefer appending the redirection to the array, such as:

```
silent=true
cmd=("sudo" "dnf" "update")
$silent && cmd+=("&>/dev/null")
"${cmd[@]}"
```

This strategy works great for functions and arguments but not for redirections. While I can apply --quiet flags to some programs to achieve this, in some cases I would like to redirect stderr, redirect to file, etc.

Comment: You have to use `eval` if you're executing shell operations dynamically.

Comment: You can only expand arguments. Redirections happen before parameter expansion.

Comment: Why don't you use a function instead of replicating a function with an array? `cmd(){ sudo dnf update;}`

Comment: BTW, I really advise against `silent=true`; treating `true` and `false` as booleans when they're really commands under-the-hood means you can be subject to arbitrary command substitution in cases where values are uninitialized or subject to injection. Safer to use `silent=0` / `silent=1`, and then `(( silent )) && ...` to avoid treating data as code.

Comment: @LéaGris But then how would I append to the function?

Comment: @anon_stackoverflock instead of adding to the function, you use an arguments array and adds arguments to it `argarry+=('another argument')`, for the function, then call `cmd "${argarray[@]}"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about *prepending* to the array?

```
# provide a function that wraps the content
silence() { "$@" >/dev/null 2>&1; }

if [ "$silent" = true ]; then
  cmd=( silence "${cmd[@]}" )
fi
"${cmd[@]}"
```

Of course, you could just use that wrapper unconditionally and make it responsible for the work:

```
maybe_silence() {
  if [ "$silent" = true ]; then
    "$@" >/dev/null 2>&1
  else
    "$@"
  fi
}

maybe_silence "${cmd[@]}"
```

---

If you *really* want to be able to support arbitrary redirections (and other shell syntax), then it makes sense to have a wrapper that just applies one redirection and leaves everything else unmodified.

```
with_redirection() {
  local redirections=$1     # first argument contains redirections to perform
  shift || return           # remove it from "$@"
  local cmd                 # create a local variable to store our command
  printf -v cmd '%q ' "$@"  # generate a string that evals to our argument list
  eval "$cmd $redirections" # run the string with the redirection following
}
```

...so you can run:

```
cmd=( with_redirection '&>/dev/null' sudo dnf update )
"${cmd[@]}"
```

...and only `&>/dev/null` is subject to `eval`-like behavior, while other contents are passed normally. You can even nest this:

```
testfunc() { echo "this is on stderr" >&2; }
cmd=( with_redirection '>out.txt' with_redirection '2>&1' testfunc
```

...and you end up with `this is on stderr` in `out.txt` (though of course, you could also run `with_redirection '>out.txt 2>&1' testfunc` to get the same effect).

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic silent redirection

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

cmd() {
  silent=$1
  if [ true = "$silent" ]
    then out=/dev/null
    else out=/dev/stdout
  fi

  sudo dnf update > "$out"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid duplicate `"${cmd[@]}"` code, you can use a subshell:

```
(
    [[ $silent == true ]] && exec &>/dev/null
    exec "${cmd[@]}"
)
```

I suggest the use of `exec` if `cmd` will always be an external command.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `eval` to process shell operations in the variable expansion.

```
declare -a cmd=("sudo" "dnf" "update" "&>/dev/null")
eval "${cmd[@]}"
```

Comment: Look like it does not work as intended: `arr=(printf '%s\n' foo 'bar baz'); eval "${arr[@]}"` → `foonbarnbazn`

Comment: Unfortunately, shell quoting rules make it hard to generalize this.

Comment: This is exactly identical in behavior to `eval "${cmd[*]}"`, except written in a way that makes it look like it _should_ respect the array's original argument boundaries (whereas in fact it does not). I'd argue that that makes it actively misleading.

Comment: Yeah. The problem is that `eval` concatenates all its arguments into a single string, losing the word boundaries.

Comment: I'm not sure how you solve that while still being able to process shell metacharacters.

Comment: Shellcheck flags this for the reason @CharlesDuffy mentions above.